# Why am I receiving an Invalid URL Error, when using Python Flask ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have been following this tutorial: https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/scrape-a-website-to-postgres-with-python-938

My app.py file looks like this (taken from the above tutorial):

```
from flask import Flask  # needed for flask-dependent libraries below
from flask import render_template  # to render the error page
from selenium import webdriver  # to grab source from URL
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # for searching through HTML
import psycopg2  # for database access

# set up Postgres database connection and cursor.
t_host = "localhost" # either "localhost", a domain name, or an IP address.
t_port = "5432" # default postgres port
t_dbname = "scrape"
t_user = "postgres"
t_pw = "********"
db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=t_host, port=t_port, dbname=t_dbname, user=t_user, password=t_pw)
db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
@app.route('/import_temp')
def import_temp():
    # set up your webdriver to use Chrome web browser
    my_web_driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

    # designate the URL we want to scrape
    #   NOTE: the long string of characters at the end of this URL below is a clue that
    #   maybe this page is so dynamic, like maybe refers to a specific web session and/or day/time,
    #   that we can't necessarily count on it to be the same more than one time.
    #   Which means... we may want to find another source for our data; one that is more
    #   dependable. That said, whatever URL you use, the methodology in this lesson stands.
    t_url = "https://weather.com/weather/today/l/7ebb344012f0c5ff88820d763da89ed94306a86c770fda50c983bf01a0f55c0d"
    # initiate scrape of website page data
    my_web_driver.get("<a href='" + t_url + "'>" + t_url + "</a>")
    # return entire page into "t_content"
    t_content = my_web_driver.page_source
    # use soup to make page content easily searchable
    soup_in_bowl = BeautifulSoup(t_content)
    # search for the UNIQUE span and class for the data we are looking for:
    o_temp = soup_in_bowl.find('span', attrs={'class': 'deg-feels'})
    # from the resulting object, "o_temp", get the text parameter and assign it to "n_temp"
    n_temp = o_temp.text

    # Build SQL for purpose of:
    #    saving the temperature data to a new row
    s = ""
    s += "INSERT INTO tbl_temperatures"
    s += "("
    s += "n_temp"
    s += ") VALUES ("
    s += "(%n_temp)"
    s += ")"

    # Trap errors for opening the file
    try:
        db_cursor.execute(s, [n_temp, n_temp])
        db_conn.commit()
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        t_msg = "Database error: " + e + "/n open() SQL: " + s
        return render_template("error_page.html", t_msg = t_msg)

    # Success!
    # Show a message to user.
    t_msg = "Successful scrape!"
    return render_template("progress.html", t_msg = t_msg)

    # Clean up the cursor and connection objects
    db_cursor.close()
    db_conn.close()
```

From looking at the Python Shell Error Log it looks like the URL is invalid:

```
FLASK_APP = app.py
FLASK_ENV = development
FLASK_DEBUG = 0
In folder /home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject
/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/venv/bin/python -m flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2021-12-28 18:13:05,988] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/app.py", line 33, in import_temp
    my_web_driver.get("<a href='" + t_url + "'>" + t_url + "</a>")
  File "/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/lloyd/PycharmProjects/flaskProject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.18.0-259.el8.x86_64 x86_64)

127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2021 18:13:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

However, I am able to visit the URL when I manually enter the address.

When I run the application a web console appears with the error msg:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Then a second web console appears with the text `data:,` in the address bar of the web browser.

Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. I did previously post a similar question re a 404 ERROR here: [Why am I receiving ERROR 404 - when attempting to use Python Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70504546/why-am-i-receiving-error-404-when-attempting-to-use-python-flask/70504624?noredirect=1#comment124631804_70504624)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these errors:

- *`[2021-12-28 18:13:05,988] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]`*
- *selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}*
- web console appears with the text *`data:,`*

are due to the the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

- You are using *chrome=96.0.4664.45*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v96.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 96

- But you are using *chromedriver=2.35.528139*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35.528139*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome v62-64

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=91.0* and the *chrome=2.35.528139*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=96.0.4664.45* (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).

Comment: Thanks for the response @DebanjanB - would you be able to tell me how to update ChromeDriver if possible? I'm not having much luck.

Comment: @LloydThomas Check the embedded links. Everything provided at your finger tips :)